# Java client reads incorrect integers from server

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

The program was suppose to be relatively straight forward. The objective was to have a server that would periodically send a rgb value (255,255,255) to all of the clients that are connected to it. In the code below I simplified it to one random value used three times. The client connects to the server just fine and is able to receive data. However, the data comes out incorrectly. I can clearly see a pattern, and I suspect it might be connected to how many bytes are sent at a time. However, I thought the buffered reader would only process read in a line if there was a new line character. Can someone explain to me why the numbers are being read in this way, and maybe point me towards the correct way to accomplish what I want?

## Example output:

10  91  9

38  371 37

33  321 32

235 2341    234

201 2001    200

65  641 64

225 2241    224

68  671 67

116 1151    115

6   51  5

## Server

```
public class Server {

    HashMap<Integer, ClientThread> clients = new HashMap<>(); // A list of clients so that they can be referenced later.

    private ServerSocket server = null; // The socket for the server
    boolean running = false; // If the server is running at all
    int responseDelta = 0; // The time between updates. Will help calculate when the server should write
                            // out all of its messages;
    int clientConnectionCount = 0; // The number of clients Connected
    int updateCounter = 1; // This is just for testing purposes

    Queue<String> incomingMessages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);
    Queue<String> outgoingMessages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }// =================================================================================================================

    public void writeMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void readMessages() {
        while (!incomingMessages.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(incomingMessages.poll());
        }
    }// =================================================================================================================

    public void sendMessages() {
        while (!outgoingMessages.isEmpty()) {
            String message = outgoingMessages.poll();
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
                clients.get(i + 1).sendMessage(message);
                ;
            }
        }
    }// =================================================================================================================

    // Starts the Server
    public void startServer() {
        System.out.println("Server was started");
        running = true;
        ConnectionThread connectionThread = new ConnectionThread();
        connectionThread.start();
        ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread();
        serverThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Reads and writes to a client connected through a socket
     * 
     * @author Sam
     *
     */
    private class ClientThread extends Thread {
        private Socket socket = null;
        private InputStream clientIn;
        private PrintWriter clientOut;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        boolean connected;

        private ClientThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
            connected = true;
            clientIn = socket.getInputStream();
            clientOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientIn));
        }// =============================================================================================================

        public void sendMessage(String message) {
            clientOut.write((message + "\n"));
            clientOut.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (connected && running) {
                    clientIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    String line = null;
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (line != null) {
                        incomingMessages.add(line);
                    }
                }
                socket.close(); // close the socket because we should be done.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Turminating socket");
                connected = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Creates a thread that will listen to incoming connections
    private class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Socket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = server.accept(); // A client has just connected
                    ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(socket); // Create a new thread to read and write to
                                                                            // the socket. If we didn't it would just
                                                                            // get dropped after scope.
                    clientThread.start();
                    clients.put(++clientConnectionCount, clientThread); // Put it in the hash map so that it can be
                                                                        // referenced later.
                    System.out.println("A new client connected");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Creates a thread that will write and read
    private class ServerThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (running) {
                readMessages();
                int color = rnd.nextInt(254)+1;
                outgoingMessages.add(color + 1 + "\t" + color + 1 + "\t" + color);
                sendMessages();
            }
        }// =============================================================================================================
    }

}// #####################################################################################################################
```

## Client

```
public class Client {


    boolean running = true;
    int port;
    String address;
    OutputStream clientOut;
    BufferedReader clientIn;




    public void connect(String address, int port) throws IOException {
        ServerConnectionThread sct = new ServerConnectionThread(new Socket("127.0.0.1", port));
        sct.start();

    }

    public void writeToServer(String data) {
        try {
            clientOut.write((data +"\n").getBytes());
            clientOut.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    private class ServerConnectionThread extends Thread{

        Socket connection;

        public ServerConnectionThread(Socket socket) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            connection = socket;
            clientIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            clientOut = connection.getOutputStream();
        }

         @Override
         public void run() {
             while(running){
                 String line = null;
                 try {
                    line = clientIn.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 if( line != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                 }
             }

         }//=============================================================================================================
    }
}
```

Comment: buffered reader would only read in a line' Sorry about that, I accidentally left in a word. That's what I get for not reviewing my question after writing it up the night before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you introduce a String to a `+` expression, you are doing string concatenation only, for the remainder of the expression.

The first `color + 1` is interpreted as mathematical addition, because no Strings have been encountered in the expression at that point.

This:

```
outgoingMessages.add(color + 1 + "\t" + color + 1 + "\t" + color);
```

is actually identical to this:

```
outgoingMessages.add(
    new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(color + 1))   // mathematical addition
    .append("\t")
    .append(String.valueOf(color))
    .append(String.valueOf(1))
    .append("\t")
    .append(String.valueOf(color))
    .toString());
```

The solution is to isolate the math expression, so it gets interpreted as math:

```
outgoingMessages.add(color + 1 + "\t" + (color + 1) + "\t" + color);
```

For clarity, I personally would parenthesize both math expressions:

```
outgoingMessages.add((color + 1) + "\t" + (color + 1) + "\t" + color);
```

Of course, `color` is one variable, so you’re printing three numbers which are all based on a single value.  A variable is not in any way “attached” to whatever previous assignments it may have add;  a variable is only set at the time an assignment is encountered in the program.

If you want three random numbers, you have to do three random number operations, and three assignments:

```
int color1 = rnd.nextInt(254) + 1;
int color2 = rnd.nextInt(254) + 1;
int color3 = rnd.nextInt(254) + 1;
outgoingMessages.add((color1 + 1) + "\t" + (color2 + 1) + "\t" + color3);
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I should have looked at it a bit longer before posting my question. I REALLY over thought that. Thanks for spotting it and pointing it out to me. I never intended to do any math there. It must have been a code fragment from something I was doing before.